# How to access a variable from a @Test method into another @Test method located in another class and another package?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, browser-automation

I'm working on Selenium POM project using Java, TestNG and Eclipse. I've `testA` and `testB`. `testA` have 2 `@Test` methods and this test submits a web Form which generates a `uniqueNumber`. testB have only 1 @Test method. Now testB have a pre-requisite to run the 2 methods from testA and I am able to run both methods from testB (using TestNG's `DependsOn`). The problem is the `uniqueNumber` generated in `testA` is not carried forward to `testB` as I tried to print it using `Sysout` and I'm getting `Null`.

1. I've delcared the `uniqueNumber` in `BaseClass` as a `public String uniqueNumber` variable since it is alphanumeric number. (I thought I should be able to use `uniqueNumber` anywhere in the project but seems like that's not the case - also I'm not sure how to declare and use a global variable in Java that is able to maintain it's updated values across all classes, in all packages.. that should be accessible throughout the whole project - Declaring `Static` don't work as it prints `Null` when accessed in another package.)
2. Both testA and testB are child class of BaseClass (Eg, I declared them as "`public class testA extends BaseClass`")
3. The 2 @Test methods in testA are declared (when I say declared, means it is declared + defined, means the methods have code in them too) as `public void testAmethodOne()` and `public void testAmethodTwo()`. Similarly 1 @Test method in testB is declared as public void `testBmethod()`.
4. testA and testB are located in different packages so I brought both in one package but still nto able to get value of `uniqueNumber` in testB. Also tried to access testA's methods by creating testA's object in testB but that too didn't work.
5. In order to use the 2 @Test methods in testA, I tried to extend testB class as "`public class testB extends testA`" but getting `Null Pointer Exception` error (I’m using POM so error is related to a page class) as "`Cannot read field <another_page_class_here> because "this.pages" is null`".
6. Also tried this way: Copied content of `testAmethodOne` into another regular method, for example, `public void regularMethod()` (which is not a `@Test` method), then created object of `testA` (for example, `objA`), tried to access `regularMethod()` via `objA.regularMethod()` but getting this `NullPointerException` error: `cannot read field <another_page_class> (NOT test class, please note that) because this.pages is null`..
7. Not sure if TestNG have any way to pass a variable from a method in one package / class to another class located in a different package / class. Since this is very simple feature, it should be covered in TestNG, I guess - but I'm not aware of it.
8. I'm stuck at the point where the `uniqueNumber`'s value is printed as Null in testB and it's value is not carry forwarded in testB. (`uniqueNumber` is accessible throughout testA though)

   ```
   // Class testA (located in package A)

   public class testA extends BaseClass {

   @BeforeMethod 
   public void startUp() {
   // Code
   }


   @AfterMethod 
   public void tearDown() {
   // Code
   }

   @Test(priority = 1)
   public void testAmethodOne() {
   // Code
   }

   @Test(priority = 2)
   public void testAmethodTwo() {
   // Code
   }

   }  // End of testA class
   ```

   // Class testB (located in package B)

   ```
   public class testB extends BaseClass {

   @BeforeMethod 
   public void startUp() {
   // Code
   }


   @AfterMethod 
   public void tearDown() {
   // Code
   }

   @Test(priority = 1)
   public void testBmethodOne(dependsOnMethods = { "testAmethodOne", "testAmethodTwo" }) {

   **// HERE uniqueNumber's value printed as Null**
   **// Tried with TestNG's ITestContext, but getting Null here**
   **// Tried by declaring uniqueNumber as "public static" and as "protected static", but getting Null here**

   }


   }  // End of testB class
   ```

Comment: Can you try using ITestContext interface of TestNG

Answer (score 0):

Even though both classes extend the same base class, while executing the test different objects of `testA` and `testB` are initialized, hence the `uniqueNumber` generated for `testA` object won't be available to `testB` object.

To solve this, either make the `uniqueNumber` as `static` (which has already been answered) or, in your test methods in `testA` and `testB` class, use `ITestContext` as a parameter.

### In testA

```java
@Test(priority = 1)
public void testAmethodOne(ITestContext ctx) {
    //code
    ctx.setAttribute("uniqueNumber", uniqueNumber);
}
```

### In testB

```java
public void testBmethod(ITestContext ctx) {
    //code
    String num = (String) ctx.getAttribute("uniqueNumber");
}
```

Comment: Since we have release coming on so I got heavy work load. Will try sometime this weekend -

Comment: Tried getting Null in testB. The moment testA completes, uniqueNumber (using ITestContext) loses it's scope and won't be available in testB. We should not forget that testB is located in another class, located in another package.

Comment: @Curious How are you running the test? Using xml ?

Comment: I'm running the test individually - not using xml yet. BTW I've below statement before class name in order to get Extent Report for individual test.

`@Listeners(MyListeners.class)`

Would appreciate if you can post the code that worked for you.. For example, BaseClass where uniqueNumber is declared, create TestA and extend to BaseClass, in TestA > @Test method assign it's value, create TestA and extend to BaseClass, in TestA > @Test method assign it's value,

Comment: @Curious If you are running each test individually, then there is no way you do this programmatically -> using the `static` or the `ITestContext` method. Once the execution is completed then the details are lost. You could only do it using some storage option like excel as you mentioned.

Comment: @ Gautham: You mean, if I included only TestA and TestB in testng.xml and run the xml, that way, am I going to carry forward / access uniqueNumber ?

Comment: @Curious Yes the `ITestContext` would be available during both the test classes are executed. The issue with running them individually is that, for each program run, memory is allocated and as soon as the program execution stops, the memory allocated to that program execution is also cleared. That is why it didn't work when you ran it individually.

Answer (score -1):

Since you've mentioned this `uniqueNumber in BaseClass as a String variable`

if you just make that as a static in your base class : -

```
protected static String uniqueNumber;
```

and initialize that during execution of `testA`, then value should be available to `testB` methods as well.

> In Java, if a field is declared static, then exactly a single copy of
> that field is created and shared among all instances of that class. It
> doesn't matter how many times we initialize a class; there will always
> be only one copy of static field belonging to it. The value of this
> static field will be shared across all object of either same of any
> different class.

[Reference link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-static)

or

[or click here to get to know more about static](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-java/)

Comment: Tried but getting TestNG Exception as `org.testng.TestNGException 
package.testB.testBmethodOne() depends on nonexistent method testAmethodOne` even though the method exist in `testA` and I copy, pasted it so I double checked that no typo exist..

Comment: @Curious : I don't see `dependsOnMethod` anywhere in your code though.

Comment: I edited my question to include "dependsOnMethod".. I have not copy, pasted the real code as I can't expose the code because of privacy issues but the structure of both class remain same as in the question.

Comment: Do you understand what static is in Java ? probably you are missing the advantage of Static fields.

Comment: Yeah -thanks for the article. Since we have release coming on so I got heavy work load. Will try sometime this weekend -

Comment: Not working as I'm still getting Null - I tried by declaring uniqueNumber as public static and protected static. My requirement is to use testA's uniqueNumber (created in testA), in testB. The only solution seems now is the old way of storing uniqueNumber's value in Excel file and access it from testB.